# Error while applying custom type in puppet

Tags: puppet

I am facing below error while applying custom type.

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/login[new]: Could not evaluate: No ability to determine if login exist`s
```

Login is the custom type.
The path where file is placed is

```
/etc/puppet/modules/demo/lib/puppet/type
```

Can anyone help with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

puppet can't find your file.  Maybe it isn't in the module path, or the permissions are wrong

Comment: The file is placed at the path mentioned.Which file permissions are you talking about?